# Bootstrap select multiple, selected option not showing when printing on PDF

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, pdf

I am working on a Bootstrap web application, where I use select multiple in a form. I need the form to be printable. But when I try to print in a pdf file, the select option of the select does not show.

```
<select multiple class="form-control">
      <option>1</option>
      <option>2</option>
      <option>3</option>
      <option>4</option>
      <option selected>5</option>
</select>
```

I wanted to post an image of the printed pdf, but I don't have enough reputation. (I don't understand why we need reputation to post an image, especially when they are useful to explain a problem)

Comment: The select option doesn't show in your PDF? How are you converting the web page to a PDF? Bootstrap has default print styles that print out multiple selects very nicely...

Comment: I do print the page and select pdf format. If I could post picture I would have shown you. I just have te display of a multiple select, but with no option selected, even if on the web page the option is selected.